# Streamlit gpt like behaviour

Tags: python, streamlit

I am using streamlit to create a gpt like interface. The problem is that i am not able to find a way to allow the user for one question at a time. So after a prompt, i want the chat input to be blocked until the response is provided. Here is the function where these changes need to be implemented.

```
    def run(self):
        print('a')
        self.display_chat_history()
        st.session_state['disabled'] = True

        st.chat_input("Send a message", disabled=st.session_state['disabled'], key='Send a message 1')
        with st.spinner("Loading data..."):
            chat = self.load_data()

        st.session_state['disabled'] = False

        if prompt := st.chat_input("Send a message", disabled=st.session_state['disabled']):
            st.session_state['disabled'] = True
            st.chat_input("The answer is being generated, please wait...", disabled=st.session_state['disabled'])
            st.chat_message("user").markdown(prompt)
            st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "user", "content": prompt})

            print(prompt)
            response = chat.ask(prompt)
            with st.chat_message("assistant"):
                st.markdown(response)
            st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": response})
            st.session_state['disabled'] = False
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://blog.streamlit.io/ai-talks-chatgpt-assistant-via-streamlit/) blog post should help you in implementing this feature. You need to change the st.session_state.disabled variable like this

```py
  def run(self):
        print('a')
        self.display_chat_history()
        if 'disabled' not in st.session_state:
            st.session_state.disabled = False

        st.chat_input("Send a message", disabled=st.session_state.disabled, key='Send a message 1')
        with st.spinner("Loading data..."):
            chat = self.load_data()

        if prompt := st.chat_input("Send a message", disabled=st.session_state.disabled):
            st.session_state.disabled = True
            st.chat_input("The answer is being generated, please wait...", disabled=st.session_state.disabled)
            st.chat_message("user").markdown(prompt)
            st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "user", "content": prompt})

            print(prompt)
            response = chat.ask(prompt)
            with st.chat_message("assistant"):
                st.markdown(response)
            st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": response})
            st.session_state.disabled = False
```

Comment: There is no .chatenabled. Also from the link you sent, where is the part that does what i have asked? Could not find something relevant.

Comment: sorry meant to share this post https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/build-conversational-apps you should add the chatenabled session state to your app and then create an if else. While your ai is generating set the session state to false for example and disable the user submit button while chatenabled is false

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet with this 'chatenabled' within the code i have sent? I do not really have a clue of how to do that.

Comment: added a code snippet in the original answer i think the problem is that you initiated the session state as False all the time

Comment: I have tried the code snippet that you sent. It allows me to send a message, after that the input box locks and the text inside is 'The answer is being...' which is good, but after the answer was generated, im no longer able to write other prompts.

Comment: does the chat input window still apear after the prompt is generated because if not you need to put your if prompt statement in a loop so it gets executed again and again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue than you and made up my own solution. I don't think it's the best, because rerun the code, but I found no other way to do this since Streamlit will only work from top to bottom (like a script)

```
import streamlit as st
import random
import time

st.title("Simple chat")

# Initialize chat history
if "messages" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.messages = []

# Display chat messages from history on app rerun
for message in st.session_state.messages:
    with st.chat_message(message["role"]):
        st.markdown(message["content"])

# Accept user input
entry_message = "Ask me a question"
prompt = st.chat_input(entry_message, key="real_chat_input")
if prompt:
    st.chat_input(entry_message, key="disabled_chat_input", disabled=True)
    # Add user message to chat history
    st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "user", "content": prompt})
    # Display user message in chat message container
    with st.chat_message("user"):
        st.markdown(prompt)

    # Display assistant response in chat message container
    with st.chat_message("assistant"):
        message_placeholder = st.empty()
        full_response = ""
        assistant_response = random.choice(
            [
                "Hello there! How can I assist you today?",
                "Hi, human! Is there anything I can help you with?",
                "Do you need help?",
            ]
        )
        # Simulate stream of response with milliseconds delay
        for chunk in assistant_response.split():
            full_response += chunk + " "
            time.sleep(0.05)
            # Add a blinking cursor to simulate typing
            message_placeholder.markdown(full_response + "▌")
        message_placeholder.markdown(full_response)
    # Add assistant response to chat history
    st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": full_response})
    st.experimental_rerun()
```

As you can see, I took the original code of the example given by streamlit. And made a double `chat_input`, one that will get the real question/prompt and the other one that will be displayed over it and thus make the first one not clickable. And of course the second one has the `disabled` argument to `True`.

But if you just have 2 `chat_input`, the user will never be able to ask a new question. So for this, after all your code logic (compute/store/display the response for example) you will need to rerun the code from top ( with `st.experimental_rerun()`) . So it will reprint all your conversation with the new answer, and stop at the first `chat_input` that is enabled.

I find it ugly, but it work.